# the constant pool lost #3 in class file

Tags: bytecode, javap

I use "javap -verbose" to parse a class file and find the constant pool lost #3, anybody can tell me the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note that the preceding entry has the type `Long` and [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.5-120) says:

> All 8-byte constants take up two entries in the `constant_pool` table of the `class` file. If a `CONSTANT_Long_info` or `CONSTANT_Double_info` structure is the item in the `constant_pool` table at index *n*, then the next usable item in the pool is located at index *n*+2. The `constant_pool` index *n*+1 must be valid but is considered unusable.

and the neat addition

> *In retrospect, making 8-byte constants take two constant pool entries was a poor choice.*

So `javap` decided to simply skip the unusable entry instead of printing something like “`#3 unusable`”…

Answer (score 0):

Longs and Doubles take up two slots in the constant pool, so the slot after them is skipped. In this case slot 2 holds a Long, so slot 3 is skipped.